# Buscar dados pelo FETCH retornando dois valores em vez de um só

Tags: react, fetch

Boa tarde. Estou tendo problemas em encontrar uma solução. Quando faço minha requisição via FETCH e printo na tela com o console.log, aparecem dois arrays de objetos em vez de um só. Segue o print na tela:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hn6n.png)

Aqui está o código em que realizo o Fetch. Na verdade estava me retornando milhares de resultados, mas estudando vi que eu tinha que usar o useEffect, pois se eu usar só o useState, por causa dele querer sempre se atualizar, ele ficava fazendo várias requisições. Usei o useEffect e resolveu parcialmente o problema, pois ainda estou tendo dois resultados em vez de um só.

```
import './ProjectForm.module.css';
import MeuInput from '../form/Input';
import MeuSelect from '../form/Select';
import Submit from '../form/Submit';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
function ProjectForm({btnText}){
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/categories',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        })
        .then((resp) => {
            if(resp.ok) return resp.json(); 
            else throw new Error("Erro!");
        })
        .then((data) => {
         setCategories(data);
         console.log(data);         
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    },[]);

    return(
        <form>
            <MeuInput type="text" placeholder="Insira o nome do projeto" name='projeto' text='Projeto'/>
            <MeuInput type="number" placeholder="Insira o orçamento total" text='Orçamento' name='budget'/>
            <MeuSelect text="Categoria" name="category_id" options={categories}/>
            <Submit name="submit" value={btnText}/>
        </form>
    );
}

export default ProjectForm;
```

Aqui está o meu Json (localhost:5000/categories) que estou pegando via Fetch:

```
{
    "projects": [],
    "categories":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Infra"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Desenvolvimento"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Design"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Planejamento"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O Hook `useEffect()` sempre executa duas vezes quando em Strict Mode.

Caso seu App tenha sido gerado com `create-react-app` (ou outra ferramenta do tipo), é comum que seu app seja renderizado em Strict Mode.

Pra conferir se esse é o caso, cheque o arquivo base do seu app (onde fica a instrução `root.render()`).

Caso seu app esteja em Strict Mode, você vai encontrar algo assim:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

// Componente que representa seu app
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  <React.StrictMode />
)
```

Mais informações sobre o Strict Mode e o porquê desse comportamento estão disponíveis na [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) e [nessa thread no repositório oficial (inglês)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502).

### Solução

A solução simples seria remover o componente `<App />` de dentro do `React.StrictMode />`, deixando somente:

```js
// ...
root.render(<App />)
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado :)

Comment: @Victorsilva bom saber que seu problema foi resolvido. Marque a resposta como "Resposta aceita", por favor. Dessa forma, outras pessoas com o mesmo problema podem encontrá-la facilmente.